# Same interface in different domains/project

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, interface

I got this issue:

Product class in a SQLBackend that implements IProduct interface.

I also got a Product in SAPBackend (ERP,  accounting software) that implements the same IProduct.

Both backend is in a different project.

I want to be able to use pass a Product between this two project so I need the same common interface.

I was thinking placing IProduct in a common interface project but if had many common cases would that lead quite many interfaces in that project. And if just lead to that I expose those interfaces to quite many projects

I wonder if there is a better case so SAPBackend and SQLBackend stand by them self and still share a common interface?

```
namespace Interfaces
{
    public interface IProduct
    {
        string name {set; get;}
    }

}
namespace Sqlbackend
{
    public class Product : IProduct
    {
        public string name { set; get; }
     }
}
namespace ERPbackend
{
    public class Product : IProduct
    {
        public string name { set; get; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Types in .NET are scoped by their assembly. Unless the interface is in the same **assembly**, it is not the same type and won't be treated as such (cast will fail, etc).

So you will **need** a reference between projects here; most commonly, to a third dll that just has the common types and interfaces in it.

The exception to this is if you are doing contract-based SOA between the two layers (for example via WCF). But I don't think that this is what you intended.

Answer (score 2):

The `IProduct` in the SQL back-end has a different meaning from the one in the ERP back-end, so I would not let them share the same interface.

Implement the two back-ends separately, then pass data between them using a pre-defined format and using a class that understands the two. That class can read the ERP `IProduct` and write to the SQL `IProduct`.

```
namespace ERPBackend
{
        interface IProduct
        {
                string Code { get; }
                string Description { get; }
        }

        class ProductForm
        {
                public IProduct CreateProductFromInput()
                {
                        ...

                        return product;
                }
        }
}

namespace SQLBackend
{
        interface IProduct
        {
                string Id { get; }
                string Description { get; }
        }

        class ProductDB
        {
                public void SaveProduct(IProduct product)
                {
                        ...
                }
        }
}

namespace MyApplication
{
        class ProductController
        {
                private ProductForm form;
                private ProductDB db;

                public ProductController(ProductForm form, ProductDB db)
                {
                        this.form = form;
                        this.db = db;
                }
                public void AddProduct()
                {              
                        ERPBackend.IProduct product1 = form.CreateProductFromInput();
                        SQLBackend.IProduct product2 =
                                new SQLBackend.MyProduct(product1.Code, product1.Description);
                        db.SaveProduct(product2);
                }
        }
}
```